# How to import a subpackage from its path in python?

Tags: python, import, package

Say we have some package with several subpackages.
But there's one subpackage X that is completely somewhere else in the file tree.
Can we still import X as if it were subpackage? (i.e. such that X can refer to the top-level package using relative imports)

Comment: relative imports only work within packages.  packages are defined by their directory structure.  So, if subpackage X isn't inside of the directory of package Y, then subpackage X isn't really a subpackage...

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you do have the `__init__.py` file inside the directory, you could go the easy route and add the packages path to the sys path ie:

```
import sys
sys.path.append(path/to/package)

import module
```

The problem with this is it will only work if the file system stays consistent. Another way that seems to work well regardless of directory structure is answered here: [Import a module from a relative path](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/279237/import-a-module-from-a-relative-path/6098238#6098238)

**Edit**

I realize I didn't understand your question as it was asked. A subpackage X is not *really* a subpackage if it is not inside of the Y package, so as far as I know you can not import it as a subpackage

Comment: This way you don't import it as a subpackage: check `print(__name__)` will just return the current name, and not all the parent packages.